# How to make self extractor exe without close and cancel button using 7 zip?

Tags: windows, installation, 7-zip, c#, winforms

I want to make a self extractor exe using 7zip. I dont want close and cancel button in the extracting window.

I am able to make extractor but its without the progress dialog.

command:

```
COPY  /Y /B 7z920_extra\7zS.sfx + Config.txt + zipFile.7z Installer.exe
```

Config File:

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title="SOFTWARE v1.0.0.0"
BeginPrompt="Do you want to install SOFTWARE v1.0.0.0?"
RunProgram="ExeToBeRun.exe"
Progress="no"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no configuration directive that controls the cancel/close button, the only way to customize it this way would be to use a program such as [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), find the progress dialog resource, and hide the buttons yourself. There should be a property called ControlBox; set that to `false`, and the close button on the progress dialog will be hidden.